# How to make the title bar of the qtwidget window minimal

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a Qt mainwindow and MDI area as a central widget in it. When I add windows in the MDI area the title bar is taking up too much space. A dock widget in the main window has a decent sized title bar and small buttons. I want some thing like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `QWidget` constructor takes a `Qt::WindowFlags` parameter that handles this. It sounds like you want:

```
QWidget w(parent, Qt::Tool);
```

If you installed the examples with Qt, run the "Window flags" example and you can play with the options to see what they do.